# SVG Filter does not binds to its icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a simple SVG icon, where I need to set the linearGradient for it. I'm trying to make it by specifying id of `filter` to the SVG body, but it does not wok, because in such way I got an empty SVG icon at all... Why?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="default___3oPC0 " style=" fill: url(#chat); filter: url(#chat); " fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width="0" width="21px" height="21px" viewBox="0 0 17 17">
    <filter id="chat">
        <linearGradient>
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#cecebf"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9b9b8c"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
    </filter>
    <path d="M7.08,3a6.14,6.14,0,0,0-2.14.37,5.34,5.34,0,0,0-1.68,1A3.64,3.64,0,0,0,1.89,7.07a3.26,3.26,0,0,0,.44,1.62,4.48,4.48,0,0,0,1.33,1.42,2,2,0,0,1,.83,1.38,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,0,.28l.12-.12A1.8,1.8,0,0,1,6,11.07h.24a6.11,6.11,0,0,0,.86.06,6.43,6.43,0,0,0,2.15-.37,5.29,5.29,0,0,0,1.67-1,3.62,3.62,0,0,0,1.38-2.74A3.62,3.62,0,0,0,10.9,4.33a5.29,5.29,0,0,0-1.67-1A6.19,6.19,0,0,0,7.08,3Zm0-2h0C11,1,14.17,3.72,14.17,7.07S11,13.14,7.08,13.14A10,10,0,0,1,6,13.07,6.57,6.57,0,0,1,.94,15v-.39A2.89,2.89,0,0,0,2.66,12.2a2.73,2.73,0,0,0,0-.41A5.78,5.78,0,0,1,0,7.07C0,3.72,3.17,1,7.08,1ZM14.7,14.6a2.32,2.32,0,0,0,1.36,2.06V17a5.46,5.46,0,0,1-4.24-1.66,7.5,7.5,0,0,1-1,.06,6.87,6.87,0,0,1-3.74-1.07,8.79,8.79,0,0,0,5.68-2.05A7.09,7.09,0,0,0,14.6,10a6.45,6.45,0,0,0,.69-2.91c0-.16,0-.33,0-.49A4.81,4.81,0,0,1,17,10.2a4.93,4.93,0,0,1-2.28,4C14.71,14.36,14.7,14.48,14.7,14.6Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://fvsch.com/svg-gradient-fill/

Comment: It is not valid to have a linearGradient as the child of a filter element.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to apply the `fill` to the path using an ID attached to the gradient

```css
svg {
  height: 200px;
}

path {
  fill: url(#chat);
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="default___3oPC0" viewBox="0 0 17 17">

        <linearGradient id="chat">
            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#cecebf"></stop>
            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#9b9b8c"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
   
    <path d="M7.08,3a6.14,6.14,0,0,0-2.14.37,5.34,5.34,0,0,0-1.68,1A3.64,3.64,0,0,0,1.89,7.07a3.26,3.26,0,0,0,.44,1.62,4.48,4.48,0,0,0,1.33,1.42,2,2,0,0,1,.83,1.38,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,0,.28l.12-.12A1.8,1.8,0,0,1,6,11.07h.24a6.11,6.11,0,0,0,.86.06,6.43,6.43,0,0,0,2.15-.37,5.29,5.29,0,0,0,1.67-1,3.62,3.62,0,0,0,1.38-2.74A3.62,3.62,0,0,0,10.9,4.33a5.29,5.29,0,0,0-1.67-1A6.19,6.19,0,0,0,7.08,3Zm0-2h0C11,1,14.17,3.72,14.17,7.07S11,13.14,7.08,13.14A10,10,0,0,1,6,13.07,6.57,6.57,0,0,1,.94,15v-.39A2.89,2.89,0,0,0,2.66,12.2a2.73,2.73,0,0,0,0-.41A5.78,5.78,0,0,1,0,7.07C0,3.72,3.17,1,7.08,1ZM14.7,14.6a2.32,2.32,0,0,0,1.36,2.06V17a5.46,5.46,0,0,1-4.24-1.66,7.5,7.5,0,0,1-1,.06,6.87,6.87,0,0,1-3.74-1.07,8.79,8.79,0,0,0,5.68-2.05A7.09,7.09,0,0,0,14.6,10a6.45,6.45,0,0,0,.69-2.91c0-.16,0-.33,0-.49A4.81,4.81,0,0,1,17,10.2a4.93,4.93,0,0,1-2.28,4C14.71,14.36,14.7,14.48,14.7,14.6Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: You have done this trick without `filter` tag. I need to add the filter by him, not directly from `linearGradient `. But, thank you for help anyway!